# Why does Istanbul show coverage for everything in a promise chain regardless of whether or not there's a test for it?

Tags: javascript, promise, code-coverage, bluebird, istanbul

My code has:

```
.then((data) => {
  let providerId = data[1].name;
  console.log(providerId);

  return global.db.Transcription.create({
    ConferenceId: foundConference.id
  })
    .then(() => {
      return {
        providerId
      };
    });
})
.then((dbTranscription) => {
  return factory.checkTranscription({
    Body: JSON.stringify({
      providerId: dbTranscription.providerId
    })
  });
})
```

Istanbul shows:
[image]

However, I have no specific test for the `checkTranscription` being called, etc. I'd rather not show that as covered. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Istanbul will provide coverage for the code within any file that satisfies the glob you provide for the `include` property. You can also specify an `exclude` glob that can be used to exclude specific files (like your test files themselves). The only way to get istanbul to ignore a specific function's implementation is to move that function (in this case `(dbTransciption) => { return factory.checkTranscription(...); }`) to its own module and exclude that file from test coverage.

Somewhere in your codebase that is being tested, it is calling that promise chain and eventually calling that function. You can see that because of the `1x` on line 71.

The question is though, why exclude that from coverage?

Comment: I didn't create an explicit test condition to see if `checkTranscription` was called. For this case, it's fine - I can simply write the test. But I'd rather the coverage show it as not covered so it can act as a `todo list` for me of what additional tests I need to write.

Comment: there are better ways to do that imho. in most test runners you can omit the function in the test case (ie `it('some test')` or `test('some other test')`) and it will mark it as skipped or TODO during the test run itself